# Trouble using microphone in Scratch

Tags: microphone, mit-scratch

When I try to record a sound for my sprite in Scratch, nothing happens. I click on the microphone to record a new sound, then click on the circle to start recording, click on "allow" when that warning pops up, but then, nothing happens. My microphone, which is just the built-in one that came with my laptop, works in other applications. I'm using Google Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m on an Asus SonicMaster laptop with a Windows 8.1 operating system. I have the same problem when using Firefox.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using the Scratch IDE, not programming.

Comment: I wish you wouldn't. With Scratch, if you can't use the IDE appropriately, you can't do the programming that you want. That said, if you have an alternate suggestion for where to post this question, I'm open to hearing it.

Comment: The Scratch forums. https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow access to microphone in camera in two places before you can record with Scratch. Look in the upper right corner of Chrome and you may see a camera with a red x next to your favorites star. Click on that icon, and you should get a dialog that ask if you want to allow camera and microphone access. Select "Always allow scratch.mit.edu to access your camera and microphone" in this dialog and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the microphone is functional. If the microphone is working, click on the video icon with an X over it then click Allow.

You might need to restart the page or even the browser. Check first.